# is this a valid option to verify the correct user logged in Django?

Tags: django, authentication

I have a login to create a new post. Before I know about LoginRequiredMixin and UserPassesTestMixin, I wanted to try something by myself in the template like this:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated and user == post.author %}
    "Show forms and things like that and can edit or delete
       if is the author of the post"
{% else %}
    "Ask the user for log in"
{% endif %}
```

Is this safe or is it a valid option?

I try to implement a user permission and authentication in Django.

Just out of curiosity, to know what's happening.

Comment: Can the user see the post if it is not their post.

Comment: Doing this in the template is not a good idea: it means that you query the post, and furthermore this is not what a template is supposed to do: a template focusses on rendering data, not doing authentication.